# White Space Right Side of Bootstrap Website

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying all kinds of solutions listed on StackOverflow to solve this problem but can't seem to get it right. There is white space on the right side of our website in the mobile view.

Any tips? Thank you so much. Been stuck for hours.

http://www.hackerparadise.org

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've added :

```
 html  {

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow-x: hidden; 

}
```

Into your **`CSS`** at the very **top** above the other classes and it seemed to fix your issue.

Comment: Hi Neophyte! Thank you very much! Although I think the correct structural answer lies in the answers provided above, yours is the patch answer I was hoping to find without spending hours fishing through and refactoring my colleague's code. Thank you!

Comment: My pleasure mate, glad I could help.

Comment: Worked. I just took the height and width out of the selector as that caused some issue with my slidein jquery animations. Thanks.

Comment: not working!!!!!

Comment: @ShadabK if you create a fiddle I might be able to help

Answer (score 3):

Most of the problems I can see is on your bootstrap structure. You are adding additional `row` without adding another div with a grid class e.g `col-md-*`

**Sample:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row"> 
        <div class="row"> <!-- additional row -->
            <div class="inner-div">
                Inner Div
            </div>    
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

A clear problem is visible in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7b0a2g5p/1/) when you scale down your browser.

**Solution:**

Before adding another `row` class element you must add first an element which has a grid `class`

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12"> <!-- DIV with a grid class -->
            <div class="row">
              <div class="inner-div">
                Inner Div
              </div>    
            </div>    
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can see it's fixed on this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ne0sm0LL/)

In your case I can see the problems under `#day` and `#about` elements.

**Under `#day`:**

[image]

**Under `#about`:**

[image]

Also the other problem is on the css. Add this to your css:

```
.btn-design {
   margin-left: 0;
   margin-right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Robin! Yes I've found this as well. I've been reading over a colleague's code and trying to figure out what the problem is. There are quite a few structural problems like this, and some bad practice! Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

In your **A Day in the life** and **Our story sections** you have 2 row classes, these need to be deleted.

```
<div id="day">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row centered" style="padding-bottom: 20px;">
      <h1>A Day in the Life</h1>
      <div id="day-images" class="row"> <-- delete extra row here
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2" align="left">
        <p class="lead">All structure is optional at Hacker Paradise, so you can find a rhythm that works for you. Here is a sample day in the life:</p>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div><!--/row-->
  </div><!-- /container -->
</div>


<section id="about">
  <div class="container pb">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="row centered"> <-- delete extra row here
        <h1>Our Story</h1>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2" align="left">

        </div>

        <br>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2" align="left">

        </div>
          <br>
        </div>
      </div><!--/row-->
    </div>

</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved by putting your row classed div inside a container class.

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <!--Your columns here>
 </div>
</div>
```

The problem is when we use a row without a container it makes it looks like that.